# Installing Yeoman on Yosemite

Tags: npm, homebrew, yeoman, osx-yosemite

I'm on Yosemite, with Homebrew, Node and NPM installed.

Homebrew 0.9.5
Node v0.12.3
NPM 2.9.1

For whatever reason, I can't get Yeoman to properly install. The install seems to go fine, no errors, but when I check to confirm the install it wont give me the --version, nor can I execute the yo function...

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:~ G$ npm install -g yo
/Users/G/npm/bin/yo -> /Users/G/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.4.6 postinstall /Users/G/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Everything looks all right!
yo@1.4.6 /Users/G/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
├── titleize@1.0.0
├── array-uniq@1.0.2
├── figures@1.3.5
├── user-home@1.1.1
├── opn@1.0.2
├── async@0.9.2
├── humanize-string@1.0.1 (decamelize@1.0.0)
├── sort-on@1.2.0 (dot-prop@2.0.0)
├── yeoman-character@1.0.1 (supports-color@1.3.1)
├── string-length@1.0.0 (strip-ansi@2.0.1)
├── cross-spawn@0.2.9 (lru-cache@2.6.4)
├── findup@0.1.5 (commander@2.1.0, colors@0.6.2)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── yosay@1.0.4 (ansi-regex@1.1.1, ansi-styles@2.0.1, word-wrap@1.0.3, strip-ansi@2.0.1, pad-component@0.0.1, taketalk@1.0.0, minimist@1.1.1)
├── root-check@1.0.0 (sudo-block@1.2.0, downgrade-root@1.1.0)
├── update-notifier@0.3.2 (is-npm@1.0.0, latest-version@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.0.0)
├── package-json@1.1.0 (registry-url@3.0.3)
├── npm-keyword@1.1.1 (registry-url@3.0.3)
├── meow@3.1.0 (object-assign@2.0.0, minimist@1.1.1, camelcase-keys@1.0.0, indent-string@1.2.1)
├── got@2.9.2 (lowercase-keys@1.0.0, object-assign@2.0.0, timed-out@2.0.0, is-stream@1.0.1, prepend-http@1.0.1, nested-error-stacks@1.0.0, statuses@1.2.1, infinity-agent@2.0.3, read-all-stream@2.1.2, duplexify@3.4.0)
├── fullname@1.1.0 (npmconf@2.1.2)
├── yeoman-environment@1.2.5 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, log-symbols@1.0.2, untildify@2.0.0, diff@1.4.0, text-table@0.2.0, debug@2.2.0, mem-fs@1.1.0, grouped-queue@0.3.0, globby@1.2.0)
├── configstore@0.3.2 (object-assign@2.0.0, xdg-basedir@1.0.1, osenv@0.1.1, graceful-fs@3.0.7, uuid@2.0.1, mkdirp@0.5.1, js-yaml@3.3.1)
├── lodash@3.9.2
├── insight@0.5.3 (object-assign@2.0.0, lodash.debounce@3.1.0, os-name@1.0.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1, request@2.55.0)
├── yeoman-doctor@1.3.2 (object-values@1.0.0, log-symbols@1.0.2, each-async@1.1.1, twig@0.7.2)
└── inquirer@0.8.5 (ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.3.7, readline2@0.1.1, rx@2.5.2)
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:~ G$ yo -v
-bash: yo: command not found
```

I've opened the .bashrc (have to use sudo to be able to open + save it). Without sudo I can't save the changes.

```
sudo nano /.bashrc
```

The bashrc file reads:

```
# NPM packages in homedir
NPM_PACKAGES="$HOME/.npm-packages"

# Tell our environment about user-installed node tools
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
# Unset manpath so we can inherit from /etc/manpath via the `manpath` command
unset MANPATH  # delete if you already modified MANPATH elsewhere in your configuration
MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"

# Tell Node about these packages
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
```

I've tried installing Node thru Homebrew first and found out about this issue which I couldnt resolve either. https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Since that didn't I blew everything away in terminal, including node, npm, and homebrew.

Now I'm stuck, npm lets me install packages grunt-cli, bower, and yeoman, but any time I try calling those packages I get:

```
-bash: yo: command not found
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the /.bashrc contents, somebody help :(

Comment: In `OS X` you should be putting the exports in `~/.bash_profile`, then quit and relaunch `Terminal`.

Comment: Tried adding this to the ~/.bash_profile and relaunching.

`echo export PATH=\"\$PATH\":~/.node/bin >> ~/.bash_profile`

No luck :/

Comment: In terminal try the command `which yo` or `which yeoman`, does anything appear?

Comment: Nothing from either.

Comment: If you do `ls /usr/local/share/npm/bin/ | grep yo`, and it outputs "yo" then try creating a symlink `ln -s /sbin/ /usr/local/share/npm/bin/yo`

Comment: hmm telling me `Gregs-MacBook-Pro:~ G$ ls /usr/local/share/npm/bin/ | grep yo
ls: /usr/local/share/npm/bin/: No such file or directory`

Comment: how about `ls /Users/G/npm/bin/ | grep "^yo$"`... if output is "yo" then do `ln -s /sbin/ /Users/G/npm/bin/yo`

Comment: `Gregs-MacBook-Pro:~ G$ ls /Users/G/npm/bin/ | grep "^yo$"`
returned
`yo`
`Gregs-MacBook-Pro:~ G$ ln -s /sbin/ /Users/G/npm/bin/yo`
returned 
`ln: /Users/G/npm/bin/yo: File exists`
now what?

Comment: Try symlinking it to your `/usr/local/bin` ... `ln -s /usr/local/bin/ /Users/G/npm/bin/yo`, then type "yo" at the prompt.

Comment: still get `ln: /Users/G/npm/bin/yo: File exists` yo returns `-bash: yo: command not found` still

Comment: Then the `yo` command is installed correctly and something with your export paths is not correct (either in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`) — that's the only other thing I see it could be. Because the `file exists` means it's already been symlinked, which would allow you to simply type `yo` and the executes the command. One more thing just to confirm, is try this at the prompt: `./Users/G/npm/bin/yo` - that should execute the `yo` command.

Comment: I think you need to change `NPM_PACKAGES="$HOME/.npm-packages"` to `NPM_PACKAGES="$HOME/npm"`

Comment: found the culprit, as initially suspected, my $PATH is messed up `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/G/.node/bin:/Users/G/.node/bin` - thing is, I cleaned out all the bashrc and bash-profiles. but I've somehow permanently added `/Users/G/.node/bin:` twice (unknowingly using a dated article that had me add those). Now I need to find a way to permanently remove it. and then add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Yosemite.

My solution was:

```
sudo find /usr/local/ -name yo
/usr/local//Cellar/node/4.2.1/libexec/npm/bin/yo
```

open $HOME/.profile

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"

export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.2.1/libexec/npm/bin:$PATH"

export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.2.1/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules
```

open new terminal:

```
yo --version
1.4.8
```

perhaps your node version is a problem. At beginning after install 'brew install node' I had too

```
node --version
v0.12.7
```

After

```
brew update
```

and reinstall node

```
node --version
v4.2.1
```